# Python - Module Not Found Error

Tags: python, import, module

I have this structure:

```
F
  f1
    __init__.py
    f.py
    g.py
  f2
    __init__.py
    h.py
```

`f2.__init__.py`:

```
from f1 import f, g
```

`f2.h.py`:

```
from f2 import f, g
```

**f2.py** is a `__main__` file. When i run f2, I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'f2'
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: python version?

Comment: @MiloLu 3.7.0 is the version

Comment: Why import `g` from `f2` when it don't contains `g`?

Answer (score 1):

if you are running main in the `f2.h.py` directly the interpreter does not seem the parent path to `F`.

An option is to use relative imports which are [different for Python 2/3](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#imports-relative-to-a-package). 
For example, add `F.__init__.py` file, then chnage `F.f2.__init__.py` to `from ..f1 import f, g` and finaly in `F.f2.h.py` import as `from F.f2 import f, g`.

Another option is adding the path to the parent destination:

```
import os, sys
sys.path += [os.path.abspath('..')]

from f2 import f, g

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('hello')
```

Comment: i used relative imports and this is what i always get an error.

 when i do `from . import f, g`, i get an ImportError which says `cannot import f from __main__`

and when i do `from .. import f, g` i get an ValueError which says `attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: please specify what Python you are using

Comment: I use python 3.7.0

Answer (score 0):

I fix it. As Jirka B. said, the problem was i run the code directley from the interpreter. After doing what should be done, everything works as i like. Thx guys.